# I can't update my Database .Net - access

Tags: .net

This is my code but it shows error which i don't know how to fix it:

```
 Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    ds.Tables("DBNewCode").Rows(inc).Item("NamEE") = TextBox1.Text
    ds.Tables("DBNewCode").Rows(inc).Item(2) = TextBox2.Text
    ds.Tables("DBNewCode").Rows(inc).Item(3) = TextBox3.Text
    ds.Tables("DBNewCode").Rows(inc).Item(4) = TextBox4.Text
    MessageBox.Show("Data updated")
    da.Update(ds, "DBNewCode") // this is the error line


End Sub


     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    TheDatabase = "/DBNewCode.mdb"
    MyDocumentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    FullDatabasePath = MyDocumentsFolder & TheDatabase

    dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM TbNewCode"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "DBNewCode")
    con.Close()


    MaxRows = ds.Tables("DBNewCode").Rows.Count
    inc = -1


End Sub
```

This is the error :

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '((No00 = ?) AND
>   ((? = 1 AND NamEE IS NULL) OR (NamEE = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND IDDD IS
>   NULL) OR (IDDD = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Location IS NULL) OR (Location =
>   ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND HP/EXT IS NULL) OR (HP/EXT = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND
>   Projector IS NULL) OR (Projector

Is there any way to fix it?  What should i do?

Comment: Which line you getting exception?

Comment: Please add stack trace of your error

Comment: Kaushik,Neeraj , ive edited it

Comment: Do you have two columns named `HP` and `EXT` or one column with a slash in its name?

Comment: Can you post the whole query, not just the part from the exception message?

Comment: Lasse , Ive edited those fieldnames.I used plain alphabetic now in my field..but ..new error appeared..which it says , **"Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records**...what should i do to fix this.? can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is something to do with the fieldnames in your Access database.
I believe you have one or more fields containing numbers and and special characters in their field names. Somehow VB/Access doesn't like the field names containing numbers (and probably special characters as well). Try renaming the fields to plain Alphabetic. Think this should solve the problem.

Comment: when i adjust the fields in access just like you told me to, it now appears new error: "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."

Comment: This is a different issue now.. and you may need to consider using OledbCommand to perform your update operation - http://techbrij.com/concurrency-violation-the-updatecommand-affected-0-of-the-expected-1-records

Comment: i've read the link you gave but can you please give me a simple example using my codes there..i'm not really good at this..i'm sorry..:( i didn't really understand which part should I change..

Comment: Nirman  I added this code for my update button :                                           'Dim updateCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update MyTable Set [Field 1]=@Field1 Where [Field 2]= @Field2 and  [Field 3] =@Field3", DBCon)
 updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Field1", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "Field 1")
        da.Update(TBNewCode) //  it says that TBNewCode is not declared

Comment: Nirman I added this code for my update button : **Dim updateCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update MyTable Set [Field 1]=@Field1 Where [Field 2]= @Field2 and [Field 3] =@Field3", DBCon) updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Field1", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "Field 1") da.Update(TBNewCode)** // it says that TBNewCode is not declared

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't have the environment to code for this (particularly, no visual studio available at this time)... but yes, what I suggest is - TBNewCode should be your table in the dataset... So instead of TBNewCode you can try out with - da.Update(ds.Tables(0))

Comment: does your dataset "ds" contain any table? it should have at least one table. If not, you may need to load the table you want to update in the dataset similar to what you have done in Form_Load event